# @ConfigurationProperties with XML-based configuration

Tags: java, spring, xml-configuration, configurationproperties

How can I re-write the following annotation-based configured class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")
class MyConfig {
  private String username;
  private String password;
}
```

To the XML-based configured class? Specifically, what is the equivalent of `@ConfigurationProperties` in the xml configuration?

Comment: I’m pretty sure you can’t do this using XML configuration. Not sure why you’d want to either, hardly anyone uses XML config in Spring nowadays.

Comment: Not every project is a new project though.